# Problems with the screen manager of Kivy Python

Tags: python, screen, kivy, transition

I'm doing a function for a kivy app and in the first screen it's necessary to insert some data inputs. My idea is to show a popup in the case you don't do the data input correctly, but I've been testing with my app and I don't know how to do it in the right way. When a button gets pressed, before you go to the next screen, the inputs are loaded and checked (at that moment in case that they weren't correct the popup is showed). Here is the code of the function that is executed when you press the button:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    Welcome:
        name: 'welcome'
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'
    AnotherScreen:
        name: 'another'

<GridLayout>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1
        BorderImage:
            # BorderImage behaves like the CSS BorderImage
            border: 10, 10, 10, 10
            source: '../ABRIL/Presentacion/etseib.jpg'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<FloatLayout>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1
        BorderImage:
            # BorderImage behaves like the CSS BorderImage
            border: 10, 10, 10, 10
            source: '../examples/widgets/sequenced_images/data/images/button_white.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Welcome>:

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "" 
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        Label:
            text: "Escriu el teu correu "
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.20}
        Label:
            text: "Benvingut a l'aplicacio ETSEIB Calendar. Per tal d'obtenir el teu arxiu amb el calendari de practiques de laboratori del GETI, segueix els seguents passos:\\n1.Inserta el teu mail (es recomana plataforma gmail o hotmail.\\n2.Selecciona quan amb quina antelacio vols rebre la notificacio de la practica\\n3.Selecciona les assignatures a la seguent pantalla.\\n4.Inserta els grups.\\n5.Revisa el teu mail i descarrega l'arxiu."
            size_hint_y: 0.5
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.36}
        Spinner:
            text: 'Selecciona quan vols rebre lavis'
            values:('1 hora abans','8 hores abans','24 hores abans')
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.28}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            on_text: root.aff(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            background_color: .7, 1, 6, 1
            on_release:root.close()
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.05}

        Button:
            text: "Next"
            font_size: 
            background_color: .7, .7, 1, 1
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.05}
            on_release:
                root.ready()
                #root.parent.current='main'
                #root.parent.transition.direction = 'left'
                #root.parent.transition= SwapTransition
        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.20}
            on_text: root.add(self.text)



<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Select Subjects (1/2)"
            font_size: 15

        Button:
            text: "Main Page"
            background_color: .7, 1, 6, 1
            on_release:
                root.parent.current='welcome'
                root.parent.transition.direction = 'right'
        Button:
            text: "Next"
            font_size: 
            background_color: .7, .7, 1, 1
            on_release:
                root.parent.current='another'
                root.parent.transition.direction = 'left'

''')

class Welcome(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Welcome, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.a = App.get_running_app()
    def add(self,p): #emmagatzema els textsinputs   
        self.a.email=p #.encode("utf-8")
    #falta enlazarlo
    def aff(self,p):
    self.a.temps=p[0:2]

    def ready(self):
        if self.a.temps=="default" or self.a.email=="":
            content=Label(text='Insert Valid Data')
            popup = Popup(title='Error',content=content,size_hint=(0.7, 0.5),background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
            popup.open()
            content.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
        else:

            self.parent.transition.direction = 'left'
            self.parent.current='main'
    def close(self):
        return  App.get_running_app().stop()

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.a = App.get_running_app()
    def ping(self, n, value): #emmagatzema les caselles marcades
        self.a.big_dict[n] = value
    def close(self):
        return  App.get_running_app().stop()
class AnotherScreen(Screen):      
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        #i=filtro.dic(0)
    a = App.get_running_app()
        t={} #dintre del diccionari t s'emmagatzemaren els inputs
    keys=[] #aquesta llista permetra ordenar les caselles seleccionades per les seguents pantalles, independentment del ordre seleccionat
        def change(self):
        self.parent.transition.direction = 'right'
                self.parent.current='second'

        b2=Button(text='Run',background_color=[0,1,0,1])
        self.add_widget(b2)
    b2.bind(on_release=change)

class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass
class SimpleKivy(App): #aquest diccionari permet emmagatzemar les caselles marcades(inicialment totes desmarcades==FALSE)
    big_dict = DictProperty({'240161': False, '240061': False, '240171': False, '240151': False, '240063': False, '240073': False, '240072': False, '240031': False, '240033': False, '240054': False, '240053': False, '240052': False, '240172': False}
)
    email=StringProperty("")
    temps=StringProperty("default")
    def build(self):
        return Root()
SimpleKivy().run()
```

The problem I'm concerned that might be in the change of screen, because I've done in the same way that kivy language. Thanks.

Comment: this code fails because it should be `self.parent` in `Welcome.ready`. With that change, does it produce the expected result?

Comment: Yes, but know I have another problem. I thought that in the case I wanted to do in another GridLayout Screen it would be in the same way, but i got the following error: `AttributeError: 'GridLayout' object has no attribute 'transition'` How could be fixed?

Comment: because that's a property of `ScreenManager`. Please show your code, preferably as a [mcve].

Comment: I have edited the code. I have editted the hole code because is too complex and may be confusing. Thanks @zeeMonkeez

Comment: again there are several indentation errors. But what gets you in trouble is that `change` will receive the sender of the event as argument. That is a `Button`, and so `self.parent.transition` does not exist. Just write `def change(sender):` and it should work.